# Powering a motor using Arduino and Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, arduino

This is my first time working with Unity and Arduino. I am trying to power a 1.5V motor attached to an Arduino Uno board, through Unity using Visual Studios and C#. I have tried numerous tutorials and searched multiple forums, but I can't get mine to work.

This is the code I have for Arduino [Arduino Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/803gT.png)

```
int incomingByte[2];
int motorPin = 10;
boolean LED = false;

void setup() {
pinMode(motorPin,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);

Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
if(Serial.available()>0)
{
  while(Serial.peek() == 'L')
  {
    Serial.read();
    incomingByte[0] = Serial.parseInt();
    if(incomingByte[0] == 1)
    {
      LED = true;
    } else {
      LED = false;
    }
  }
  while(Serial.available()>0)
  {
    Serial.read();
  }
}
ledCheck();
}

void ledCheck()
{
if (LED)
{
digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH);
} else {
digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);
}
return;
}
```

This is the code I have in my Unity script [Unity Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrL5O.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class MotorPower : MonoBehaviour {

SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600);

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void ledOn()
{
    sp.Open();
    sp.WriteLine("L1");
    sp.Close();
}

public void ledOff()
{
    sp.Open();
    sp.WriteLine("L0");
    sp.Close();
}
```

}

I added the unity script to an empty GameObject in the unity project and created two buttons, go and stop, and connected the ledOn and ledOff methods to them.

The Arduino code runs the motor when using the serial monitor but when using unity the motor does not run, only the RX light on the board flashes.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you enter the `loop()` method and there is no serial data? It looks like `Serial.Available()` will return 0, and the loop method will return, having done nothing. Is `loop` called repeatedly?

Comment: Yes the loop() runs over and over, constantly checking for Serial.available(). How do i combat if there is no serial data. I currently don't have a method for it?